# Get all users which passed the exam

Tags: django, django-queryset

I need help in django queries. 
I have ExamResult model which keep results of exam.
How get all users which passed the exam and are in the same study group.

1. ExamResult model

```
    class ExamResult(Model):
    exam = ForeignKey(Exam, blank=False, null=False, on_delete=CASCADE)
    score = IntegerField()
    user = ForeignKey('Accounts.UserAccount', blank=False, null=False, on_delete=CASCADE, )
    exam_date = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False, null=False)
```

2. StudyGroup model

```
class StudyGroup(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False, null=False)
```

Comment: So what you have tried so far? and _how_ do you define being **passed** in a exam?

Comment: Sorry for my English. I done sql query "Select ua.id From Accounts_useraccount ua WHERE ua.study_group_id = 1 AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Exams_examresult er WHERE ua.id = er.user_id AND er.exam_id = 23)" study_group and exam_id I am getting from kwargs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
users = UserAccount.objects.filter(
    exam_result__pk=23,
    study_group__pk=1
)
```

Comment: Sorry for my English. Count of score doesn't matter. I have sql query Select ua.id From Accounts_useraccount ua WHERE ua.study_group_id = 1 AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Exams_examresult er WHERE ua.id = er.user_id AND er.exam_id = 23)

Comment: I edited the answer according to your comment. Does it answer your question?

Comment: users = UserAccount.objects.filter(exam_result__exam_id=self.kwargs['exam_id'], study_group=self.kwargs['group_id']).distinct () Its work.